# Azure ADAL - How to get refresh token / how to refresh access token for nodejs backend server to server connection?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I'm using adal-node module for my Node JS backend to write file to Azure Storage. The authentication works fine, but the access token I got only valid for 1 hour. And so far I couldn't find anyway to refresh my access token. Can someone advise?

I've tried to get refresh token. But the auth function I'm using below don't send refresh token back. I've also try to just create a new token after a while using the same auth function, but it turns out the token is always the same.

Here's the code I use to get the access token.

```
var AuthenticationContext = require('adal-node').AuthenticationContext;

var authorityHostUrl = 'https://login.windows.net';
var tenant = 'myTenant.onmicrosoft.com'; // AAD Tenant name.
var authorityUrl = authorityHostUrl + '/' + tenant;
var applicationId = 'yourApplicationIdHere'; // Application Id of app registered under AAD.
var clientSecret = 'yourAADIssuedClientSecretHere'; // Secret generated for app. Read this environment variable.
var resource = '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'; // URI that identifies the resource for which the token is valid.

var context = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUrl);

context.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resource, applicationId, clientSecret, function(err, tokenResponse) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('well that didn\'t work: ' + err.stack);
  } else {
    console.log(tokenResponse);
  }
});
```

Need some way to refresh my access token so that my long running job wouldn't stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get a new access token.

In the Client Credentials flow, a refresh token is not returned. (See [Section 4.4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4.3) of the OAuth 2.0 spec.)

Comment: I tried, but `acquireTokenWithClientCredentials` always gives me the same access token, before it gets expired. Any other API i can use to get a new access token?

Comment: The library will give you the same token as long as it's still valid (because there's no need to get a new one). If it's approaching expiry time, then it will get a new one instead.